# Which event is fired in SWT when table content changes

Tags: java, events, swt, jface

I have a `TableViewer` object in SWT with some filters. So when the filter changes the content of the `Table` of `TableViewer`changes too. I searched for an event that is fired when a `TableItem` is added or removed from the `Table` but found nothing. Is there such an event?

I want to use all the shown rows for a calculation, so my handler can manage the statistics - like a sum of a column i.e. - and that's why I need the event.

Comment: I didn't find any event for changed table content. Anyway I found another solution to my Problem: in my Filter there is a method setting the filter condition and calling `TableViewer.refresh()`. When the execution returns from `refresh()` I used the refreshed table to calculate my statistics.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter do you call setInput explicitely? If so, look at your contentprovider inputChanged method. I think it could be a solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi Bela, thanks fot you're asnwer! I don't call `setInput`. I filter by extending `ViewerFilter` and overriding `ViewerFilter.select()`. There I only check if the row meets a predifined condition and return true or false. At the end I use `TableViewer.addFilter()` to add my extended `ViewerFilter`.